# Change from Xslt 1.0 to XSLT 2.0 with just version changes

Tags: xml, xslt, guava, saxon, xalan

We use XalanJ 2.7.1 with 1.0 compatible xslt file. We want to change to xslt 2.0 with Saxon-EE 9.7 so we want to make some feasibility study if this works faster. From all previously research from the Internet is said that XalanJ is the slowest.

Out transformation with XalanJ average time is 989ms but with Saxon-EE with just changed version from 1.0 to 2.0 with the same xslt rules run for 1100ms average.

Does it means that we have to rewrite our xslt files or it is probable error with  the performance measurement?
And if the transformation has to be changed, what in particular?

**Edit 2:**

For performance testing pourposes we just create sample application using

```
final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

TransformerFactory factory = new EnterpriseTransformerFactory();
Source xsl = new StreamSource(FileUtils.openInputStream(fileXSL), fileXSL.getAbsolutePath());
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
stopwatch.start();
transformer.transform(input, output);
stopwatch.stop();
```

Then use GugleGuava's Stopwatch to measure the time for the transfor method. I execute the transformation 1000 times and ignore the first 100 executions and measure the average time.

**Edit 3:** 
Total time: 1816.153 milliseconds
I made statistic analysis using Saxon profiler

```html
<table border="border" cellpadding="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>file</th>
      <th>line</th>
      <th>instruction</th>
      <th>count</th>
      <th>average time (gross)</th>
      <th>total time (gross)</th>
      <th>average time (net)</th>
      <th>total time (net)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>234</td>
      <td>template tplCreateAttribute</td>
      <td align="right">5281262</td>
      <td align="right">0.007</td>
      <td align="right">36443.790</td>
      <td align="right">0.007</td>
      <td align="right">36443.790</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>248</td>
      <td>template tplCreateDateAttribute</td>
      <td align="right">1215364</td>
      <td align="right">0.010</td>
      <td align="right">11722.446</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">9177.567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>265</td>
      <td>template tplCreateBoolAttribute</td>
      <td align="right">934716</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">7438.999</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">7438.999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>392</td>
      <td>template fnMathRandomNumber</td>
      <td align="right">1215364</td>
      <td align="right">0.005</td>
      <td align="right">5937.933</td>
      <td align="right">0.005</td>
      <td align="right">5937.933</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>338</td>
      <td>template tplCreateAttributeOBID</td>
      <td align="right">607682</td>
      <td align="right">0.018</td>
      <td align="right">11004.523</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">5066.590</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>template dcx:object[@class = 'Object']</td>
      <td align="right">311572</td>
      <td align="right">2.599</td>
      <td align="right">809778.821</td>
      <td align="right">0.014</td>
      <td align="right">4316.423</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>318</td>
      <td>template tplCreateAttributeWithDefault</td>
      <td align="right">311572</td>
      <td align="right">0.011</td>
      <td align="right">3500.819</td>
      <td align="right">0.011</td>
      <td align="right">3500.819</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>365</td>
      <td>template tplCreateAttributeObjectState</td>
      <td align="right">311572</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">2645.134</td>
      <td align="right">0.008</td>
      <td align="right">2645.134</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>376</td>
      <td>template fnDateConvert</td>
      <td align="right">592220</td>
      <td align="right">0.004</td>
      <td align="right">2544.879</td>
      <td align="right">0.004</td>
      <td align="right">2544.879</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>201</td>
      <td>template dcx:object[@class = 'Object Smpl']</td>
      <td align="right">296110</td>
      <td align="right">2.530</td>
      <td align="right">749090.244</td>
      <td align="right">0.005</td>
      <td align="right">1545.430</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>template /</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">78836.780</td>
      <td align="right">78836.780</td>
      <td align="right">219.216</td>
      <td align="right">219.216</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>"*_transformation.xsl"</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>variable constAlphabetUpperCase</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">0.229</td>
      <td align="right">0.458</td>
      <td align="right">0.229</td>
      <td align="right">0.458</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: At least explain what you did (running Saxon from the command line or from a Java application, using Saxon's API and tree model or using JAXP and perhaps DOM as the input?) and how and what you measured.

Comment: What kind of `input` is that that you pass in, can you use a `StreamSource` or a `SAXSource` to allow Saxon to use its own tree model? Or is that a `DOMSource` you use?

Comment: StreamSource I use

Answer (score 1):

Saxon is often much faster than Xalan, but not always. It all depends: with performance the devil is in the detail. Sometimes the performance is dominated by parsing rather than transformation cost. As Martin Honnen hints, using a DOMSource with Saxon can be very slow. (Saxon gets a big boost from its use of integer fingerprints for matching node names, and that can't be done when running on a standard DOM.)

Running an unchanged XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with a 2.0 processor is always a bit of a challenge, because there will be very little type information (e.g. no type declarations on variables) so the processor has to decide everything at run-time, e.g. whether addition is integer, double, float, or decimal, and whether any conversions are needed. By contrast, a 1.0 process only has double arithmetic so the decisions are a lot easier. So a 2.0 processor has an intrinsic disadvantage; but usually Saxon still wins.

If you're looking for anecdotal evidence on the internet, you need to be aware that people don't always make it clear whether they're talking about the old Xalan-J interpreter or the newer XSLTC compiler, which is much faster.

One thing we don't know from your question is whether the XSLT code is well-written or not. This is a double-edged sword. Saxon-EE has a stronger optimiser than most other products. If the code is very well-written, or if it is very simple, that's no great advantage because not much can be done to improve it. Equally, if the code is monstrously bad, then no optimizer is going to save it. In between there is a middle ground where good optimization can sometimes make things go 20 times faster (or more). As I say, the devil is in the detail.

Comment: It is hard to say if the xslt is writen bad if I now that it is  monstrously bad I would have been fix it. 
And if xslt simple, here it depends what you are compareing. But for the test I use the simplest transformation from the project. We try to write good xslt-s because of the performance problems, we do no use "//" for xPath selection,we use named templates, try to reduce choose statements and so on. The xslt contains business specific logic so I can not post it here.

Comment: Well, if you've avoided a construct like "//" because it performs badly in Xalan, then that's a shame, because that's one of the constructs that Saxon optimizes rather nicely: in fact it can give you excellent performance gains. This kind of discussion basically goes nowhere until you start looking at the code and diving into the detail.

Comment: Yes I understand and you are right, but we have tons of xslt reaching 1 MB and it will be hell to extract different scenarios, but I will try.

The main purpose of the topic was to understand is there exists some drawbacks of just using changing the version of the transformation for saxon EE like this which you mentioned that in Xpath we have strings but xslt processor must decide run-time which is the actual type.So in this situation transformation is slower because of the wrong usage of the xslt 2.0, because of the desire to reduce the job for the migration. I want to know things like this

Comment: Have you tried running Saxon with -TP:profile.html? The output will identify whether there are any particular hotspots in your stylesheet. (This also emphasises that "performance" isn't just about raw numbers, it's also about tools to help you look for inefficiencies).

Comment: I did not know about that. Thanks I will collect the statistic and will add it here. You are gold man, Mr Kay.